# Holidays or holiday?

Tags: phrase-request, singular-vs-plural

Ahead of a period of school holidays, should someone say to someone else: "Happy holidays!" or "Good holidays" or rather "Have a good holiday!" or "Enjoy your holiday!"?

Comment: Saying "happy holidays" is common but essentially meaningless, because it could refer to any number of holidays, but most people don't celebrate more than one.

Comment: In any case, the OP is asking about the school holidays (called vacation in AmE?). The longest and most notable such holiday period is that in the summer. So I don't think it would be common for Americans to say "happy holidays" in that case. For the winter break they might.

Comment: In the U.S. we call those *breaks* or *vacations*.  To wish someone a *happy holiday* before they take that break would be to wish them well on whatever holiday occurred during that time frame.  So during *spring break*, which is often a week long break that includes Easter during one of the weekends, your wish of *have a happy holiday* would be roughly interpreted as *Happy Easter* and not as *enjoy your weeklong break*.  To express that you would say something like, *Have a great vacation.*  If no actual Holiday occurred during that week, saying *Happy Holiday* would sound odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Happy Holidays" is a formulaic expression to wish someone a good Christmas, New Year, or Hanukkah. It is specifically said in late December as an alternative to "Merry Christmas".  You don't use it, for example, in Spring time before Easter or "Spring break"

You can say "Have a good holiday" or "Enjoy your holiday" as a general expression before the start of someone's holiday.  In British English "a holiday" can mean a school break or a vacation. You can use "Have a good X" for most things that you hope could be good.  "X" could be "meal", "evening out", "sleep" or "holiday" (for example)

So just prior to the winter holidays that coincide with Christmas you could say "Happy holidays!".  But before any school break you could, in British English say "Enjoy your holiday".

Answer (score 0):

In British English, it would depend on whether you intended the wish to be for the whole period while school was closed - 'the holidays' - or for a particular trip you knew that that person was going to take - 'your holiday'.

Comment: You haven't said what the answer would be in either of those scenarios.  I suggest "Have a nice break" or "Enjoy the holidays" if it's the period of school closure that we're talking about, and "Have a nice trip" or "Enjoy your holiday" if it's a particular trip that you know about.  (If it's about the period when the school's closed, it only really makes sense as an exchange between students.  Parents will be even busier than normal!)

Comment: @rjpond - I would have thought it was obvious that the expressions using the plural are appropriate for the first, those using the singular for the second.

Comment: Perhaps, but the OP is not a native speaker, and certainly, two of the suggestions in the original question ("happy holidays", "good holidays") aren't things we'd say in British English, whether in the singular or plural, and probably aren't things that Americans would say in this context either (they mainly seem to say "happy holidays" in December rather than in the summer).

Comment: @rjpond - So we are restricted to one of the four response options provided by the OP?  Such an answer will of course be opinion based.

Comment: @EllieK Certainly not. I was merely saying that, in failing to recommend any particular expression or give any examples, this answer falls short - in my opinion.